# Deleting elements from a list based on their relative position to one another

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a data set where I often get pairs of spikes that occur randomly but the pair is always separated within $n$ places of each other. I.e. the spacing between the pairs, in index, is always constant.

Is there a way, given some other condition to pick out the first spike (I use something like `Select[IndexedData[[1;;,{1,2,3}]], #[[3]] > threshold &]`)to then remove the $n \pm1$ points after this peak?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data to work with? Also, do you know "n" or is that something that you don't know a priori?

Comment: @Fraccalo I know that $n$ is always 41. I will attach a data sample now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you may use something like

```
data[[Complement[Range@len, n + 1 + peaks]]]
```

where I'm assuming one-dimensional data for simplicity, `len` is the size of your dataset and `peaks` is a list of **positions** for your peaks.

For example, take

```
n = 3;
len = 20;
data = RandomInteger[100, len]
```

giving the following sample data:

```
{72, 5, 36, 57, 97, 95, 86, 11, 5, 4, 35, 82, 59, 88, 6, 53, 6, 100, 39, 53}
```

then you find the peak positions with

```
peaks = Select[Range@len, data[[#]] > 90 &]
```

giving in this case

```
{5, 6, 18}
```

Then the line above results in

```
{72, 5, 36, 57, 97, 86, 11, 4, 35, 88, 6, 53, 100, 39}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html).  For example, using Fidel's data for consistency:

```
n = 3;
len = 20;
data = {72, 5, 36, 57, 97, 95, 86, 11, 5, 4, 35, 82, 59, 88, 6, 53, 6, 100, 39, 53};

mask = UnitStep[90 - data]
mask *= PadRight[mask, len, 1, n]

Pick[data, mask, 1]
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}
> {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}
>
> {72, 5, 36, 57, 86, 4, 35, 82, 59, 88, 6, 53, 6, 39, 53}
> ```

Note that here I drop both the detected peaks at positions 5, 6, 18 and also the elements offset by three.  If you choose this method reference [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep.html), [`PadRight`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadRight.html), [`TimesBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimesBy.html).